# Is there a way to just pull out all of a certain index without going through the results and rebuilding a 2nd temp array?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript

I've got multiple sheets with anywhere from 500 - 10,000 rows each that I need to find specific values in a given column. Ex. Sheet A, B, C have information about a bunch of products. I search for Product Id in A, B, C (with 3 individual `for` loops) and output the results into a new sheet.

To search through each sheet I use `.getValues()` for a finite range and use a for loop:

```
for (var i=0;i<a.length,i++) {
    if (a[i][indexWithId] == ProductId) {
        tempArray.push(a[i]);
    }
}
```

and then once I have my `tempArray` I insert it into the new sheet with `.setValues()`.

**My question is:** Is there a way to just pull out all of a certain index without going through the results and rebuilding a 2nd temp array? Eg. of these 30 columns, I only need 3. I'd like to display information about each product, but in sections, not in a single row. The ideal output would look like:

```
> ---Status section from sheet A---
> Id    |    name    |    status
> 001      productX       active
> 
> ---Category section from sheet A---
> Id    |    name    |    product category
> 001      productX            sales
```

The only way I can think to accomplish this is to brute force or hard code something like this for every section I want to create:

```
var tempArray2 = [];
for (var i=0;i<tempArray.length,i++) {
    tempArray2[i] = [];
    tempArray2[i].push(tempArray[i][IdIndex]);
    tempArray2[i].push(tempArray[i][NameIndex]);
    tempArray2[i].push(tempArray[i][StatusIndex]);
    }
}
```

If my answer is a loop, that's fine. But if there's a function that spits out all values of a given set of indexes without a loop, that'd be cool too.

Comment: Have you considered doing it with a regular formula (not a script)? Something like `={'Sheet A'!A:A, 'Sheet A'!D:D}` gives you the `A` and `D` columns of Sheet A.

Comment: I was actually using an `=arrayformula` with multiple `query` but the overhead and recalculation was crazy. I then was using `.setFormula` and doing a query for each parameter was also taking too long. In the end, a loop has been quickest, if not the prettiest.

Comment: Have you considered to ask this question on [codereview.se]?